# Java ME: Emulator shows no GUI

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans 8 and I've activated the Java Me and installed the platform. But when I click run project I see this window:
[image]

Where is phone emulator with the GUI view and how can I get it?

Comment: It looks like your project/IDE isn't set up to develop software to target a phone, but rather an embedded device without a display.

Comment: @hexafraction: So how can I set it up for mobile phones? would you please help me?

Comment: I don't personally know NetBeans. However, it would likely make sense to use an IDE designed for Android, like Android Studio (based on IntelliJ IDEA). If you are developing for an older Java-based (non-Android) phone that uses J2ME or Java ME, then that is a completely different thing, that I honestly have no idea about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-client/java-me.html) you can develop to MIDP with Netbeans. But at the [download page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) is not available on any bundle.

I downloaded the Java SE version and went on Tools .. Plugins .. Available. There I found Java ME plugins. After install, unfortunately the New Project wizard only showed Java ME Embedded option. I believe this is what happened with you. Be sure to check the Visual Mobile Designer (Mobility category) this will add the options to Java ME projects.

But you still need to add Java ME Platform manually... Download it [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html). Then go to Tools .. Java Platforms .. Add Platform .. Java ME CLDC .. Selected the folder where you installed the SDK.